# How to keep AWS ECS from shutting down during a critical moment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

Is there a way to ensure an AWS ECS container instance doesn't shut down in the middle of running a critical task?

I have an auto-scaling AWS ECS service that scales the number of instances based on CPU usage. These instances process long-running batch jobs that may take anywhere from 5 to 30 minutes.

The problem is that sometimes, during a scale-down, an instance that's actively running a critical job gets shut down which ultimately causes the job to fail.

Comment: I disagree with the closing vote. With devops and the cloud, the lines between development and infrastructure become increasingly blurry and that is a good thing. I think the strickt distinction between development and operations is outdated and obsolete, and artificially keeping that distinction alive doesn't do any good. In the cloud, infrastructure *is* code, and in my opinion, Stack Overflow should remove that specific closing reason altogether.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a feature called **managed termination protection**.

When the scaling policy reduces the number of instances, it has no control over which instances actually terminate. The default behavior of the auto-scaling group may well terminate instances that are running tasks, even though there are instances not running tasks. This is where managed termination protection comes into the picture. With this option enabled, ECS dynamically manage instance termination protection on your behalf.

Please have a look at [Controlling which Auto Scaling instances terminate during scale in](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html) and specifically the section [Instance scale-in protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-instance-termination.html#instance-protection) in the AWS documentation.